# How to exclude 404 page with Timber

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I know I can include the 404 page in Timber with

```
{% if fn('is_404') %}
  404 page content
{% endif %}
```

But how can I say if page is NOT the 404 page?

Comment: `{% if not fn('is_404') %}`

Comment: I never even thought of that! I was going down the path of !=. Thanks!!